# Increase score - NSString issue

Tags: objective-c, ios

i have this code for receiving score when Player touch an object:

```
- (void)  match:(GKMatch *)match
 didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
     fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID{



    NSString *incomingDataAsString =
    [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *existingText = score.text;

    NSString *finalText =
    [existingText stringByAppendingFormat:@"Pasc = %@",
     incomingDataAsString];

    [self.score setText:finalText];

    [incomingDataAsString release];

}
```

But, as result, my score shows like that: "Pasc = 123456", how can I make it to show, single digit increasing. (Replacing number 1 with 2, and 2 with 3..

Thanks.

Comment: Uh, don't keep appending to the same string?

Comment: i need something like, existing text + 1

Comment: (You could chop off the previous character and add another, but that would be the wrong way to do it.  The right way is to separately store "prototypeText" somewhere and append to that, rather than relying on the "score" label to store your prototype for you.)

Comment: You're not telling the truth about something.  The above code would produce "Pasc = 1Pasc = 2Pasc = 3...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following, hope it help.

```
   NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [incomingDataAsString length]); // 0 is -->x<-- position 0
    NSString *finalText = [existingText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",incomingDataAsString];

    [self.score setText:finalText];
```

I forgot that we can do like this, you mentioned that, just remove "Pasc =", and concern only @"%@", then just

```
[self.score setText:incomingDataAsString];
```

Please give me a feedback, so I understand what's happen, then I can edit my code to help you :), thanks.

Comment: Hey.. Thanks WORKS. But, When my score is 10, if i increase one more time, it show 110, 120, 130

Comment: wait for me a bit bro, ley me think of the solution

Comment: 7 is a position and 1 is range, so could you replace incomingDataAsString length with the range, so when it is 10 length will be 2 :)

Comment: just remove "Pasc = " use only "@%@" to be easy

Comment: yeah, so you have to change the position to be the correct one too, so it should be 0.

Comment: yes, but when score is more than 9, there appearing the problem. Instead of 11, 12, it shows me 110, 1210, 13210

Comment: Now stuck at 9, it doesn't increase after 9

Comment: can you nslog [incomingDataAsString length], so if it is 10, it should be 2 and when 11 come in it should replace 10 with 11 because of length 2

Comment: :) more than willing to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If Score is a `number` like an `NSInteger`, treat it and store it as what it is a `NSInteger` or a `NSNumber` if you need it to be an object.
And convert it to a `NSString` only for display purpose.

Answer (score 0):

`self.score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pasc = %@", incomingDataAsString];`